# Generic type parameter extending type "any" is not of type "any" anymore

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, generic-type-parameters

I was not able to find an answer to the question why function `thisDoesNotWork` causes an error. In contrast, function `thisWorks` transpiles the line `anyArgs.whatever();` without complaining, and I would expect this to work in the other function, too.

```js
function thisWorks(anyArgs: any): any { 
  console.log(anyArgs);
  anyArgs.whatever(); // NO ERROR
  return anyArgs;
}

function thisDoesNotWork<T extends any>(anyArgs: T): T { 
  console.log(anyArgs);
  anyArgs.whatever(); // ERROR: Property 'whatever' does not exist on type 'T'.
  return anyArgs;
}
```

Since `T` extends type `any`, `T` should be some sort of `any`, too, so why does the line `anyArgs.whatever();` cause an error here?

Comment: This behavior was explicitly added in TS3.5, see [breaking change notes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#type-parameters-that-extend-any-no-longer-act-as-any).  I don't know if this deserves its own answer, or if we should ask @OvidijusParsiunas to add this info to the existing answer.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for pointing out the change notes. However, the logic and the reasoning behind that change is not explained. To me it looks like constraining to `any` does not make any sense, so the `any` constraint is simply erased.

Comment: Thanks for the commend @jcalz, I will update my answer!

Comment: I read the document and are you sure it is not a change in TS3.9?

Comment: Yeah oops it’s 3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<T extends any>(anyArgs:T)` is not the same as `(anyArgs:any)`. Generics add constrains to the type of values that are passed-in or returned from a method/function. So the generic `<T extends any>(anyArgs:T)` parameter tells the compiler that yes - anything can be passed in, however because it does not know what the type of `T` actually is ahead of time, it will not permit access or manipulation of the `anyArgs` value.

Hence, `<T extends any>(anyArgs:T)` is actually the same as `<T>(anyArgs:T)` rather than being same as `(anyArgs:any)`.

As mentioned by @jcalz, this behaviour was only added to TypeScript in version 3.9 and previous versions did in fact regard `extends any` to be the same as `any`. Link to this change [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#type-parameters-that-extend-any-no-longer-act-as-any).

Comment: What puzzles me is the term "extends". To me `T extends MyClass` means we have a type `T` that has all properties of type `MyClass`, so on `T` we can safely access all properties that are part of `MyClass`. And thus my conclusion was that `T extends any` also allows me to access all properties of `any`, and since `any` disables these checks, I would consider access to any property valid. Following your explanation I would think the term should rather read "T constrains any" instead of "... extends...".

Comment: Correct. The ```T extends any``` just makes it more confusing and should usually be replaced by a simple ```T``` to denote the actual behaviour.

Comment: `constrains` is exactly what is meant by the `extends` keyword in generic parameters. I think you can safely swap that out mentally when you see it in that case.